# Active class bootstrap menu with paddings

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a menu in bootstrap, and have made paddings between each point, so it isnt clutched up in a row, which I like better. But I have some issues in regards to the active class.

I have a padding of 3 pixels, left and right on each li element in my navbar, but when I add an active class it doesn't work like I want it to.
On my active class I want background to be #fff, instead of #fafafa. And when I change it, the #fafafa does not disappear, and the #fff is in the background - behind my li element. I want the #fafafa to disappear on the active class, and the background to fit with my 3px paddings.

Thanks for the help, hope I can get some.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2kt9pvL8/)

I would like for this example the link at:

```
<li class="active1"><a href="#">Forside</a></li>
```

to be #FFF, without box-shadow (basically like my hover effect)

Comment: Try making a jsfiddle or bootply of your example and sharing it; that way we can debug a live version of your issue. As your question is right now, I have no idea how we could help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2kt9pvL8/
Sorry about that ;-)
I would like for this example the link at:
"<li class="active1"><a href="#">Forside</a></li>"
to be #FFF, without box-shadow

Comment: No worries. And don't forget, you can edit your question at any time, so you don't have to post stuff like that in the comments. It might get missed or ignored down here.

Comment: There we go, should be a bit clearer now :)

Comment: I check your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kt9pvL8/ and there seems to be no box-shadow but just a background-color of #FFF to the active link. What exactly do you want??

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, then you have most of what you want - the active item is #fff background and no shadow already (I am looking at it in Firefox). If you are also wanting the active item to be the same length as the other, non-active, items, then remove the margin: 0 auto !important from the .active {...} styling.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this is the css you'll need to change:

```
.active1 a { background-color: #fff !important; margin: auto !important; box-shadow: none !important; }
```

Adding the `a` to your class will apply your style to all anchor elements within your `.active1` class.

It is best practice to avoid using the `!important` keyword unless absolutely necessary. Use specificity to style instead.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kt9pvL8/2/